# how to fill array with contents of another array that has different size using loops

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to fill an array sized by [4344][20] with the contents of other array sized by [5430][20]. I wrote the following code and it has no errors. It filled the X_train correctly, but the Y_train didn't filled successfully. it remained zeros as its initialized.

my code:

```
void split(int fold, int array_X_set[5430][20], int array_Y_set[5430],
    int X_train[4344][20], int Y_train[4344],
    int X_test[1086][20], int Y_test[1086])
{
    int rows = 5430;
    int cols = 20;
    int division = 1086;
    int nTest = 0, nTrain = 0, nTest1 = 0, nTrain1 = 0;
    switch (fold) {
    case 1:
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
              if (i < division) {
                  X_test[nTest][nTest1] = array_X_set[i][j];
                  Y_test[nTest] = array_Y_set[i];
                  nTest1++;
                }
             
              else {
                  X_train[nTrain][nTrain1] = array_X_set[i][j];
                  Y_train[nTrain] = array_Y_set[i];
                  nTrain1++;
               } 
                   
          }
              }
     break;
 
another condition :
 for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
         if (i >= 1086 && i <= 2171) {
             X_test[i][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
             Y_test[i] = array_Y_set[i];
         }

         else {
             X_train[i - division][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
             Y_train[i - division] = array_Y_set[i];
         }
          }
         }
```

Comment: In C++ you can't assign arrays. Instead I suggest using memcpy to copy the data, or using std::array which can be assigned

Comment: I just update the code, please check

Comment: Hi! Your code is full of bugs. Please write functions that do just one thing, but do it well. Your code, contarary to your description, attempts to change `X_test`, `Y_test`, `X_train`, `Y_train`.   Please try and learn how to use a debugger.  Try to think when and why your array indices, like `x1` and `x2`, are changed, and if this is what you really wanted.

Comment: @zkoza my code is working very well except the part of filling the Y_test and Y_train arrays (they are 1D arrays as you see in the code). I want to make sure why it didn't fill them correctly. I think I miss something

Comment: Did you try step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: I run the code using visual studio

Comment: @user555 Invest 30 minutes of your time and learn to use Visual Studio's debugger, it's super easy to use and super powerful.  These 30 minuts will quickly pay off.

Comment: If you decide to use the opening scope brace `{` at the end of the line, please ensure the indentation is strictly correct.

Comment: When `nTrain` is being modified?

Comment: @zkoza yes good question, I try to increment it but also no good results

Comment: Could you please try to tell exactly what your function is intended to do? If I get you right only 2 arrays of the code you have given are relevant for you problem? How should the one array be merged be done? Whats the result you want? Read [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this code, so that you don't need extra variable like nTest, nTrain, nTest1, nTrain1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
      if (i < division) {
          X_test[i][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
          Y_test[i] = array_Y_set[i];
      } else {
          X_train[i-division][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
          Y_train[i-division] = array_Y_set[i];
      }
  }
}
```

**updated**:

Another condition:

if you have 10 elements in array

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
         ^  ^  ^  ^
```

you want to put index 3~6 to new array, in new array, its index would be 0~3

1. so for the part >=3 && <=6 would be newArr[i-3] = originalArr[i]

and if you want to put index 0~2 and 7~9 to new array, in new array, its index would be 0~2 and 3~5

2. so for the part <3 would be newArr[i] = originalArr[i]
3. the part >6 would be newArr[i-(6-3+1)] = originalArr[i], (6-3+1) means the element count between the part >=3 && <=6

Here is the code in your condition:
(>=1086 && <=2171 in test array, <1086 || >2172 in train array)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
    if (i >= 1086 && i <= 2171) {
      X_test[i - 1086][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
      Y_test[i - 1086] = array_Y_set[i];
    }
    else { 
      if(i<1086){
        X_train[i][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
        Y_train[i] = array_Y_set[i];
      }else{
        X_train[i - (2171-1086+1)][j] = array_X_set[i][j];
        Y_train[i - (2171-1086+1)] = array_Y_set[i];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try and back to you

Comment: thank you Jane for your answer, it works successfully, but I have a question:

Comment: What if I change the if  condition  if (i < division) into another condition such as if (i >= 1086 && i <= 2171) , What the new indexes of the arrays wil be ??

Comment: it means that you want to split three part, <1086, 1086~2171, >2171 , to three differnent array?

Comment: I want to fill the arrays as in the previous code but this time with different condition( specific contents of the original array), did you got what I mean ?

Comment: I just update the question ,, please check the code

Comment: so <1086 and >2171 with put in x_train and 1086~2071 put in x_test, right?

Comment: Unfortunately , it is not working well. the output is not as expected

Comment: did you try [i-2072] or [i - (2171-1086+1)]? I have updated again a few minutes ago.

Comment: wooow,  thank you very much for your cooperation and being patient, the code perfectly well, thank you very much Jane , you save my life

Comment: you're welcome! btw, is Y_test correct? It seems I forgot to use Y_test[i - 1086] instead of Y_test[i], if it's wrong I'll update answer again.

Comment: Actually, I suppose that you forget to use Y_test[i - 1086], so I change it in my code and it runs successfully. Yes ,You can update the answer . Thank you again Jane

Comment: I've corrected it and add some explanation in updated version. you can check if you need the explanation.